# Team Development offline

Tags: version-control

I want a version control system tool, but offline.Like I develop a project on my computer,and someone is working on a different part of this project on a different computer.Is there a tool that allows to me bring the project from different computer to mine and sync all the changes.

I would like to have all functionalities of a version control system like diff,rollback,commit

Please suggest a suitable tool.

Comment: In fact, besides Git there are a number of other distributed version control systems, that all work offline or online. Do a Google search and you will find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git is a free and open source distributed version control system designed to handle everything from small to very large projects with speed and efficiency.

http://git-scm.com

It can be used online or offline easily.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the version control tools on the market support these features: diff, rollback, commit, offline, etc. I list some tools here for your reference:

Open Source

1. Git
2. SVN

Commercial

1. SourceAnywhere (developed by the company I'm working for)
2. Microsoft Team Foundation Server